# Python: Function works when tested with an integer but not in within apply() lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my function:

```
def recommendation(row):
    if row['fitness_discipline'] == 'Cycling':
        if (row.avg_workout_length > row.total_workout_length) & (row.next_class == 'last'):                
            filtered_classes = classes[(classes.fitness_discipline != row.prev_class) & (classes.fitness_discipline != row.fitness_discipline)& (classes.class_length < row.avg_workout_length*0.5)].sort_values(by='times_taken',ascending=False)
            if filtered_classes.empty:
                reco= ''
            else:
                reco = filtered_classes.iloc[0]['class'] + ', ' + filtered_classes.iloc[1]['class'] + ', '+ filtered_classes.iloc[-1]['class']
            return reco
        elif (row.total_workout_length >= row.avg_workout_length) & (row.next_class == 'last'):
            filtered_classes = classes[(classes.fitness_discipline != row.prev_class) & (classes.fitness_discipline != row.fitness_discipline)& (classes.class_length <= 15)].sort_values(by='times_taken',ascending=False)
            if filtered_classes.empty:
                reco= ''
            else:
                reco = filtered_classes.iloc[0]['class'] + ', ' + filtered_classes.iloc[1]['class'] + ', '+ filtered_classes.iloc[-1]['class']
            return reco
        return None
    return None
```

The above is just for context as when I run it, it runs perfectly as it should. In other words when I test it:

```
recommendation(df.iloc[12345])
```

Where '12345' is a random index in dataframe "df", I get the exact output I want as a string.

Then, when I do:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: recommendation(x),axis=1)
```

I expect a new column to be created in df that takes each row and applies the function, outputting the result in the 'new_column" column based on each row. But no matter what I try, it fails and I usually get

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'
```

as an error.

Comment: If `filtered_classes` sometimes comes out empty, error arises. It's not empty for 12345'th row, but apperantly it is for some other(s).

Comment: @MustafaAydın I updated the function. should that work?

Comment: Yes, it seems fine. Does it work `:)`?

Comment: Still running! haha